Ver y Desver la contraseña con PasswordBox en WPF
El componente PasswordBox de WPF no tiene una opción para verse la contraseña? La opción para activar el típico ojo que hay en el campo contraseña en todos los formularios.
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.passwordbox?view=windowsdesktop-8.0
he mirado este link y he preguntado a chatgpt pero no lo encuentro.
Muchas gracias, disculpad las molestias

Nop, no tiene, pero seguro hay mil controles por ahi que replicaron lo que vos queres...
